# Custom assembly rdlc Report sql client permission error

Tags: rdlc

I have rdlc report which uses external assembly, the custom assembly has Connection string define but i am unable to open the connection string while running report here what i have done so far :

Adding custom assembly :
[image]

Define assembly naming in expression rdlc :
[image]

here's is my code in Custom assembly :

```html
        public string GradeCal(int SubjDivID, decimal Perc)
        {
            Bll_BlockPlan ObjClass = new Bll_BlockPlan();


        
            SqlConnection oConn = new SqlConnection();
            oConn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=******;Initial Catalog=PSIDB_Test; User ID=sa; Password=*****;Persist Security Info=True";

            try
            {
                oConn.Open();

            }

            catch(Exception ex)
            {

                string msg = ex.Message;
            }
            SqlCommand oCmd = new SqlCommand();
            oCmd.Connection = oConn;
            oCmd.CommandText = "Select  V.Title as Grade From  (Select  *, IsNull(Lead(Percentage) Over (Order By Percentage),(Select Max(Percentage)+.01 From LP_SubjectDivisionsGrades WHERE SubjectDivisionsID = @SubDivID)) NextPercentage From LP_SubjectDivisionsGrades where SubjectDivisionsID = @SubDivID) G inner join LP_SubjectGrades v on v.id = g.GradeID where @Perc >= G.Percentage And @Perc < G.NextPercentage";

            oCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubDivID", SubjDivID);
            oCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Perc", Perc);
            string nRetVal = oCmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

            return nRetVal;
        }
```

The exception comes in Custom assembly class which is :

Request for the permission of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientPermission, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

Please i dont have any idea where wud i set the permission data.sqlclient ??

Kindly help me out